# Why is TCP data being fragmented smaller than the MSS?

Tags: c, linux, networking, tcp

I'm sending 550 bytes from a client to a server using TCP. I want to send all 550 bytes at once. But sometimes, it gets broken into really small parts, smaller than the MSS. (If the first part sent is under 150 bytes, the server doesn't work well. They're asking me to fix the client.)

Q1. Why might the client break the data?
Q2. Can routers break the data too? Why?
Q3. Can I code it to send all 550 bytes at once?

I know that TCP is a streaming protocol. Just between you and me, what I really want is for the server to fix the program.

Code:

```
result = send(sock, buff, 550, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

Network:

```
client Linux 5.10.9 --- (probably some routers) --- server
```

I have some logs from the server. The problems are with numbers 48753, 48758, and 48760. All of them have something called a PSH flag, so I think there's another reason they got broken apart.

Log1: Sent all 550 bytes at once.

```
No. Time    Protocol    Src port    Dest port   Length  Info
17095   2023-08-27 10:12:53.980532  TCP 46140   xxxx    74  46140 → xxxx [SYN] Seq=0 Win=13660 Len=0 MSS=1366 WS=1 SACK_PERM TSval=881659354 TSecr=0
17096   2023-08-27 10:12:53.980547  TCP xxxx    46140   74  xxxx → 46140 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=917771748 TSecr=881659354 WS=512
17097   2023-08-27 10:12:53.980845  TCP 46140   xxxx    66  46140 → xxxx [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=13660 Len=0 TSval=881659355 TSecr=917771748
17150   2023-08-27 10:12:54.419811  TCP 46140   xxxx    616 46140 → xxxx [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=13660 Len=550 TSval=881659794 TSecr=917771748
17151   2023-08-27 10:12:54.419827  TCP xxxx    46140   66  xxxx → 46140 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=551 Win=30208 Len=0 TSval=917772187 TSecr=881659794
17152   2023-08-27 10:12:54.425033  TCP xxxx    46140   216 xxxx → 46140 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=551 Win=30208 Len=150 TSval=917772192 TSecr=881659794
17153   2023-08-27 10:12:54.425330  TCP 46140   xxxx    66  46140 → xxxx [ACK] Seq=551 Ack=151 Win=13810 Len=0 TSval=881659799 TSecr=917772192
17219   2023-08-27 10:12:54.929602  TCP 46140   xxxx    66  46140 → xxxx [FIN, ACK] Seq=551 Ack=151 Win=13810 Len=0 TSval=881660304 TSecr=917772192
17220   2023-08-27 10:12:54.931022  TCP xxxx    46140   66  xxxx → 46140 [FIN, ACK] Seq=151 Ack=552 Win=30208 Len=0 TSval=917772698 TSecr=881660304
17221   2023-08-27 10:12:54.931274  TCP 46140   xxxx    66  46140 → xxxx [ACK] Seq=552 Ack=152 Win=13810 Len=0 TSval=881660305 TSecr=917772698
```

Log2: The data got broken into small parts.

```
No. Time    Protocol    Src port    Dest port   Length  Info
45751   2023-08-27 10:17:50.150219  TCP 46146   xxxx    74  46146 → xxxx [SYN] Seq=0 Win=13660 Len=0 MSS=1366 WS=1 SACK_PERM TSval=881955525 TSecr=0
45752   2023-08-27 10:17:50.150238  TCP xxxx    46146   74  xxxx → 46146 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=918067917 TSecr=881955525 WS=512
45753   2023-08-27 10:17:50.150538  TCP 46146   xxxx    66  46146 → xxxx [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=13660 Len=0 TSval=881955525 TSecr=918067917
48753   2023-08-27 10:18:20.864291  TCP 46146   xxxx    138 46146 → xxxx [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=13660 Len=72 TSval=881986239 TSecr=918067917
48754   2023-08-27 10:18:20.864311  TCP xxxx    46146   66  xxxx → 46146 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=73 Win=29184 Len=0 TSval=918098631 TSecr=881986239
48758   2023-08-27 10:18:20.875946  TCP 46146   xxxx    174 46146 → xxxx [PSH, ACK] Seq=73 Ack=1 Win=13660 Len=108 TSval=881986251 TSecr=918098631
48759   2023-08-27 10:18:20.875959  TCP xxxx    46146   66  xxxx → 46146 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=181 Win=29184 Len=0 TSval=918098643 TSecr=881986251
48760   2023-08-27 10:18:20.878712  TCP 46146   xxxx    436 46146 → xxxx [PSH, ACK] Seq=181 Ack=1 Win=13660 Len=370 TSval=881986253 TSecr=918098643
48761   2023-08-27 10:18:20.878737  TCP xxxx    46146   66  xxxx → 46146 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=551 Win=30208 Len=0 TSval=918098646 TSecr=881986253
48762   2023-08-27 10:18:20.878743  TCP 46146   xxxx    66  46146 → xxxx [FIN, ACK] Seq=551 Ack=1 Win=13660 Len=0 TSval=881986253 TSecr=918098643
48763   2023-08-27 10:18:20.884644  TCP xxxx    46146   66  xxxx → 46146 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=552 Win=30208 Len=0 TSval=918098652 TSecr=881986253
```

Log3: Tried again right after and it wasn't broken.

```
No. Time    Protocol    Src port    Dest port   Length  Info
48819   2023-08-27 10:18:21.725898  TCP 46148   xxxx    74  46148 → xxxx [SYN] Seq=0 Win=13660 Len=0 MSS=1366 WS=1 SACK_PERM TSval=881987100 TSecr=0
48820   2023-08-27 10:18:21.725918  TCP xxxx    46148   74  xxxx → 46148 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=918099493 TSecr=881987100 WS=512
48821   2023-08-27 10:18:21.726152  TCP 46148   xxxx    66  46148 → xxxx [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=13660 Len=0 TSval=881987101 TSecr=918099493
48864   2023-08-27 10:18:22.174604  TCP 46148   xxxx    616 46148 → xxxx [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=13660 Len=550 TSval=881987549 TSecr=918099493
48865   2023-08-27 10:18:22.174619  TCP xxxx    46148   66  xxxx → 46148 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=551 Win=30208 Len=0 TSval=918099942 TSecr=881987549
48866   2023-08-27 10:18:22.181427  TCP xxxx    46148   216 xxxx → 46148 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=551 Win=30208 Len=150 TSval=918099948 TSecr=881987549
48867   2023-08-27 10:18:22.181696  TCP 46148   xxxx    66  46148 → xxxx [ACK] Seq=551 Ack=151 Win=13810 Len=0 TSval=881987556 TSecr=918099948
48943   2023-08-27 10:18:22.704057  TCP 46148   xxxx    66  46148 → xxxx [FIN, ACK] Seq=551 Ack=151 Win=13810 Len=0 TSval=881988079 TSecr=918099948
48944   2023-08-27 10:18:22.705356  TCP xxxx    46148   66  xxxx → 46148 [FIN, ACK] Seq=151 Ack=552 Win=30208 Len=0 TSval=918100472 TSecr=881988079
48945   2023-08-27 10:18:22.705566  TCP 46148   xxxx    66  46148 → xxxx [ACK] Seq=552 Ack=152 Win=13810 Len=0 TSval=881988080 TSecr=918100472
```

Comment: *the server doesn't work well. They're asking me to fix the client.*  "They" are somewhere in the Bermuda Triangle of Brain Dead between "unreasonable", "living on a planet where the sky ain't blue", and "idiot".  The server and/or the protocol itself being used is fundamentally **broken** if it can't handle the stream like that.  And the code is already trying to send the full packet.

Comment: "They" need to read this: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8095#section-3.1.1  There is no way possible to "fix" the problem of TCP packet fragmentation - it can happen at any time, and it is not a violation of any TCP specifications when it does. If "they" continue to say you need to fix it, you need to tell them they also have to get every network admin on every device that handles the data to "fix" their hardware, and every system administrator of every system your client runs on to "fix" the OS. Then tell "them" your code is already "fixed" because it's already sending 550 bytes

Comment: While I fully agree that the server is broken it might be helpful to shift the blame even more from your client and thus make it no longer your problem. Get a packet capture not only from the server but also a matching packet capture at the same time from the client. Hopefully you can prove then that the data left the client the way you've intended and got fragmented somewhere on the way, i.e. outside of your control.

Comment: Is there some other data already in the send buffer before you call `send(sock, buff, 550, MSG_NOSIGNAL);`? If so, could flushing it and wait (maybe 500ms or so) before that call help?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: based on the sequence numbers in the tcpdump the 550 bytes are the first data in the connection, so there cannot be anything already in the send buffer.

Comment: Are your sure that the MSS is larger? Remember the MSS used by the sender is what the receiver sent in the handshake, not the MSS on the sender.

Comment: Can you clarify why you think MSS is not working, in the context of your code? You should run a local trace, but `550` is your buffer size. MSS means "Maximum Segment Size" and that appears to be set elsewhere in the API, if I googled correctly.

Comment: The server people are probably in the wrong, but it's hard to say. The PSH flag is a TCP flag, so they weren't added via IP fragmentation. They could come from you or some obnoxious network device like a load balancer. In theory, the PSH flag causes delivery of buffered data to the app, the application layer code shouldn't be dependent on a PUSH as defining a command or the end of message.

Comment: @RonMaupin: I think the MSS is larger. No.45751 says the MSS is 1366, and No.45752 says it's 1460. However, if I'm wrong, please let me know why.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich: Thank you for the wonderful idea. Capturing logs on the client side is challenging as it requires cooperation from the end users, but I am exploring ways to do so.

Comment: @benc: I believe the MSS is functioning correctly. However, given that the client transmitted a segment of only 72 bytes, far less than the specified MSS of 1366 bytes, there might be another underlying issue I'm not aware of.

Comment: @benc: Yes, I am aware that the PSH flag is, as you said, a TCP flag. And this issue is related to TCP segmentation, not IP fragmentation. Could this be coming from some obnoxious network device like a load balancer?

Comment: @kachi789: You really need a trace of your outbound data from your client's physical interface, there's so many possibilities.

Comment: @Andrew Henle: Thank you for the comment. I think so, too. Is there a section that explicitly states **'It can happen at any time'**  ? I read RFC 8095 (and 9293), but I was unable to find it.